# How to start Matlab after a clean install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I have downloaded and run the installer for matlab with destination `/home/matlab`, where matlab is the folder I created. Installation completed successfully. Now how do I start the program in Ubuntu?

Comment: It's called MATLAB. Also this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

To start MATLAB® on Linux® platforms, type `matlab` at the operating system prompt.

Create A MATLAB Launcher/shortcut
Automatic option: install package "matlab-support", `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` or via the Software Center on the dashboard.

Manual option as follows.

1. Get an icon:

`sudo wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png -O /usr/share/icons/matlab.png`

2. Get the launcher file:

`sudo wget 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=matlab-r2012a.desktop' -O /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop`

If you have the student version of MATLAB (or simply the 32 bit version) on a 64 bit system, you will need to modify this file. Run

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop`

Then uncomment #Exec=matlab -arch=glnx86 -desktop and comment Exec=matlab -desktop (by adding or removing the # character).

If you get two MATLAB launcher icons in your Unity laucher, try uncommenting the following line in `/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop`:

`StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit`

Original article at [matlab community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)

Answer (score 0):

- Start it from command line:
  `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020b/bin/matlab &`
  (replace the path with wherever is your installation located)
  or
- Install `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` to get the [MATLAB shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB#Create_A_MATLAB_Launcher.2Fshortcut).